# How to upload document on an Article using article id when it does not even exists

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, blogs

currently i am in a very weird situation. I am trying to upload document using article id and user id to an article. But the issue is when I try to select article id from the document model, it gives error that article doesnt exists.

And tbh that is true, because how can i upload document to an article when it doesnt even exists. So how can i use article id in such situation?

Below is my document model in which i am sending user id and article id for uploading document.

documentmodels.py

```
class DocumentModel(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="DOCUMENT_ID")
    user_fk_doc=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name="users_fk_doc")
    article_fk_doc=models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="articles_fk_doc")
    document=models.FileField(max_length=350,  validators=[FileExtensionValidator(extensions)], upload_to=uploaded_files)
    filename=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    filesize=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    mimetype=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and below is the articles models,

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="ARTICLE_ID")
    headline=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    abstract=models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    published=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags=models.ManyToManyField('Tags', related_name='tags', blank=True)
    isDraft=models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    isFavourite=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="favourite", blank=True)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="articles")
```

EDITED

Actually i am trying to implement upload file feature in article which is in editor.
I can upload the document for the article according to user but the issue is in the start:

1: There is no article in the beginning so I have no article id

2: So if I have no article id, I cannot upload the document without article id else it throws error that
field cannot be null, or field s required

3: I want to know how can I solve the issue where in the beginning I dont have any article id and upload the document

document views.py

```
class DocumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    
    serializer_class=DocumentSerializer
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes= [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    parser_classes=[FormParser, MultiPartParser]

    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return DocumentModel.objects.select_related('user_fk_doc').all()

    #Cache



    @action(detail=True, methods =['get'], url_path='download')
    def download(self, request, pk):
        try:
            document_file=DocumentModel.objects.get(id=pk, user_fk_doc=self.request.user)
            file_path=document_file.document.path
            print(file_path)
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
                    response=HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)[0])
                    response['Content-Disposition'] = "Inline; filename={}".format(os.path.basename(file_path))
                    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
                    return response
            return Response({'error' : 'There is no document file of the user'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        except DocumentModel.DoesNotExist as e:
            return Response({'error': 'Document for this user does not exists'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Article views.py

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
```

Comment: Can you post your view (that doesn't work)? It's not clear what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think the way I was trying to post document for article was complicated.
I was adding the article id into document when article id was not even created till then.

So the solution that I came upon is instead of using these two foreign keys in document model below:

```
    user_fk_doc=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name="users_fk_doc")
    article_fk_doc=models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="articles_fk_doc")
```

I simply added a many to many field in article model. so my model became like this below:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="ARTICLE_ID")
    headline=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    abstract=models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    published=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags=models.ManyToManyField('Tags', related_name='tags', blank=True)
    **files=models.ManyToManyField('DocumentModel', related_name='uploads', blank=True)**
    isDraft=models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    isFavourite=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="favourite", blank=True)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="articles")
```

and then simply **upload document through document model** and then use **many to many** field to filter all the documents according to user and article.

In the end simply execute such query depending on your situation to filter documents

```
DocumentModel.objects.get(id=pk,uploads__created_by_id=self.request.user.id)
```